# WCF serializing objects with inheritance

Tags: wcf, serialization, inheritance

Here's what I am trying to do. I have a WCF restful service, and I need to serialize multiple objects that inherit from the same class.

There is nothing in any of the base classes that needs to be serialized.

Here is a minimal demo that shows what I want to get to work:

```
<DataContract()>
Public Class BaseObj

    <DataMember()>
    Public ID As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal idval As Integer)
        ID = idval
    End Sub

End Class

<DataContract()>
Public Class TestObj1
    Inherits BaseObj

    Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer)
        MyBase.New(id)
    End Sub

End Class

' Different from TestObj1 in real life
<DataContract()>
Public Class TestObj2
    Inherits BaseObj

    Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer)
        MyBase.New(id)
    End Sub

End Class
```

And here's the code that uses it:

```
<ServiceContract()>
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)>
Public Class Service1

    <WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="Test?reqReportID={reqReportID}")>
    Public Function GetCollection(ByVal reqReportID As Integer) As List(Of BaseObj)

        Dim myObjs As New List(Of BaseObj)
        myObjs.Add(New TestObj1(20))
        myObjs.Add(New TestObj2(20))
        Return myObjs

    End Function

End Class
```

If I declare the List to be a list of `TestObj1` instead, everything works.

Am I missing some crucial concept here?

EDIT:

The problem gains a new level of confusion by looking at this code:

```
    <WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="Test?reqReportID={reqReportID}")>
    Public Function GetCollection(ByVal reqReportID As Integer) As BaseObj()

        Dim myObjs As New List(Of BaseObj)
        myObjs.Add(New TestObj1(20))
        myObjs.Add(New TestObj2(20))

        '   This guy works. Yields correct result of [{"ID":20},{"ID":20}] )
        Dim testStr As String = New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myObjs.ToArray())

        '   But this guy still has problems...
        Return myObjs.ToArray()

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>What you are missing is a `[KnownType]` attribute.</s>

WCF requires a way of knowing all possible types so that it could publish the WSDL.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx).

### UPDATE

The problem is that `List<T>` is **not covariant**.

Use `IEnumerable<T>` instead.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion, but if I change the line `<DataContract()>` to `<DataContract(),KnownType(GetType(BaseObj))>` for both `TestObj1` and `TestObj2`, the behavior remains unchanged. Is the problem that I am adding that wrong?

Comment: Sorry I have updated my answer. I noticed you did not need KnownType

Comment: @Aliostad, I really appreciate your input, however I'm still not getting it to work. I changed the return type to a simple array and it still has the same behavior. To make things more confusing, I can manually serialize the array it works just fine (see edits to question).

Comment: Array is not always covariant as well. I have updated my answer.Use `IEnumerable<T>` and that should work.

Comment: @Aliostad, I'm not sure that's explaining the reason, because manually serializing it *does* work. Changing the return type to `IEnumerable(Of BaseObj)` did not seem to change the behavior at all.

Comment: Ok, I got something (sortof) working by making the decorator on `BaseObj` to `<DataContract(), KnownType(GetType(TestObj1)), KnownType(GetType(TestObj2))>`, which technically answers this question. I've rephrased what it is I really want to do in a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641750/wcf-datacontracts-and-polymorphism. Thanks for your help.