# WCF DataContracts and Polymorphism

Tags: json, vb.net, wcf, polymorphism

Here's what I want to do. This should (theoretically) be very simple.

Say I have a WCF service with the following code (bare bones functionality):

```
<DataContract()>
Public Class BaseObj
    <DataMember()>
    Public ID As Integer
End Class


<DataContract()>
Public Class TestObj1
    Inherits BaseObj

    Public Sub New(ByVal idval As Integer)
        ID = idval
    End Sub

End Class


<DataContract()>
Public Class TestObj2
    Inherits BaseObj

    Public Sub New(ByVal idval As Integer)
        ID = idval
    End Sub

    <DataMember()>
    Public DoNotShow As String = "fail"

End Class
```

Here is the code I want to write:

```
<WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="Test?reqReportID={reqReportID}")>
Public Function GetCollection(ByVal reqReportID As Integer) As List(Of BaseObj)

    Dim myObjs as New List(Of BaseObj)
    myObjs.add(new TestObj1(1))
    myObjs.add(new TestObj2(2))
    return myObjs

End Function
```

I want the JSON response to look exactly like this: `[{"ID":1},{"ID":2}]`

Now the code that I have currently returns an empty response (no error thrown, no information passed). I can get it to return *something* by doing this:

```
<DataContract(), KnownType(GetType(TestObj1)), KnownType(GetType(TestObj2))>
Public Class BaseObj
    <DataMember()>
    Public ID As Integer
End Class
```

However the response adds a "__type" to the JSON object, and also adds "DoNotShow" to the JSON object (not a good thing).

The problem here is that I *do not want* to pass information that is unique to each object. I only want information that is *common to each object through the base class*. Nothing I can do will change it, and unless I am missing something, it seems as though the authors of WCF had a very bassackwards view of OO programming when they created this.

Any insight you here at SO might have would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, why does it matter?  With the example you gave I'm not sure I'm following the why it's important.

One option I have off of the top of my head is to inherit TestObj2 from TestObj1.  Then I would take off the knowntype(gettype(testobj2)).

If you want to dynamically add known types then you should call the datacontractjsonserializer yourself.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx

Edit:  this will result in two TestObj1 objects on the client side.  Not sure if you want that behavior.

Comment: It matters because while TestObj1 and TestObj2 are very similar in this example, they are extremely different in the real application. The idea is that I have multiple objects that are built very differently, but have a few common features--the essence of what OO means. I *only want the common features* on the receiving end, but do not want to exclude the possibility of returning a list of objects of TestObj1 in a different service request. It is Object Oriented 101, and I am at a loss for words why I cannot do it in WCF.

Answer (score 0):

If your collection is only typed to BaseObj I don't think it's possible for the serializer to produce the JSON you are looking for.

If it were to simply produce `[{"ID":1},{"ID":2}]`, there is no way for the recipient to distinguish between the types. How would the other end determine that the first object is of type TestObj1 but the second object is of type TestObj2?

Comment: in what universe would I possibly want the receiver to distinguish between types TestObj1 and TestObj2 when returning a collection of BaseObj objects? I want them both treated as BaseObj (thus the reason I am returning them as BaseObj). If I *did* want to distinguish between them, then I would not be transmitting BaseObj, but rather would be returning a collection of TestObj1 objects and a separate collection of TestObj2 objects. It is polymorphism 101, yet it seems foreign to the designers of WCF.

Comment: @stargazer, that would be a universe where the receiver needs to deserialise the object so it is semantically equivalent to the one that was sent. That's the only universe I have ever worked in and it's the universe WCF was designed for. I don't see a way for The desired serialisation output you've specified to work in that universe - there simply is not sufficient information. You have said "they are extremely different in the real application" so it seems that is the universe you are also in. Or am I missing something?

Comment: in that universe, you are demanding that the service expose 100% of its functionality to the client. It is absurd to assume that the client and server need to be perfect mirrors of one another and assumptions such as that have no place in a framework. The client should be told only what it needs to know.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the absurdity. WCF is doing exactly what you have told it to do. It sounds as if you are attempting to use the server objects to define the message contracts and WCF is, quite logically, attempting to serialise the semantically critical information (including the type, where it cannot be unambiguously inferred) into the messages. WCF is built around message contracts. If the server objects do not provide a workable specification for your message contracts, then you can define other objects that do reflect what you wish to transmit to the client.